# AJAX not working, success function is working?

Tags: php, html, ajax

the success function is working but the data is not going in the database

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ChatText").keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var ChatText = $("#ChatText").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'InsertMessage.php',
                data:{ChatText:ChatText},
                success:function(){
                    $("#ChatText").val("");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");
    },15000000);

    $("#ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connectToDB.php";

if(isset($_POST['ChatText'])){
    $uid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $gid = $_SESSION['GameId'];
    $ct = $_POST['ChatText'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `chats`( `ChatUserId`, `chatGameId`, `ChatText`) VALUES ('$uid','$gid',$ct);";
    $result = mysqli_query($_db , $sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please share your php code, we can't do anything with this

Comment: i used this php code with a submit button and it worked fine

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: Are you sure is $_db and not $db ?

Comment: yes....i think the php code is working fine cuz I used it with a submit button and it worked fine

Comment: All of your code, this is not all

Comment: [obligatory SQL injection warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) ... which would actually circumvent the issue you have with not having quotes around the `$ct` variable ... `VALUES ('$uid','$gid',$ct)`. I'm almost certain that, with the correct error debugging, you'd find an SQL error here. Assuming your *ChatText* `<textarea>` has the name `ChatText`  of course.

Comment: thanks it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

one thing u could do to debug is that echo your sql query and see if you get the correct query that works. You can event try out that query in phpMyAdmin and see whats going on. Hard to tell anything without debug.